Monoidal categories with canonical left-strengths of monads
It is well-known that every monad on Set is left-strong and that left-strength on a Set-monad is unique.
Is there an abstract characterization of monoidal categories $C$ for which every monad on $C$ is left-strong and the strengths are unique?
Best I am aware of is the sufficient condition for uniqueness by Moggi mentioned on
nLab page about strong monads.
